# C# Clone a panel to other form

Tags: c#, winforms, copy, clone, panel

My question is very simple to explain, but it's being difficult to get the answer.
I have 2 forms. In form1 I have nothing, and in form2 I have a panel with controls inside. Basically, when I click in a button from form1 I want to clone/copy the panel from form2 to form1, maintaining all it's controls and properties equal.

I already create an instance of form2 in the button click event, and made the panel public in form2.designer.cs so I can access it without opening form2. i tried to have a panel in form1 so that I would put that panel equal to the other, but didn't work. I'm out of ideas and can't find anything on the net. Can anybody help me please?
Sorry for any english mistake.

Comment: it's not easy to `copy` all the properties of all the controls. and the most important thing is **We actually never do such a thing in real applications**

Comment: I'm trying to do this for one purpose. I want my application to merge all my forms. So with a panel, I would pass all my controls from form2 to form1. You can see it like an mdi application, but slightly different.

Comment: Basically you can see it as an "mdi" application of panels.

Comment: If you want to do it via the clipboard...then here is a way e.g. you could use if each of your forms was a separate process and you needed to exchange the control data, or maybe you want to support copy and not just cut/paste. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12976/How-to-Clone-Serialize-Copy-Paste-a-Windows-Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a dirty hack to me, but for what it's worth: Create a reference to form2 from form1. When you perform your "copy", you create a list of all controls on form1, and then clear form1. You then add the controls to form2.

Add this method into form1...form2 is your reference to your second form. Fire this with an event like a button click.

```
public void CopyControls()
{
    List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        ctrls.Add(c);
    }
    this.Controls.Clear();
    form2.Controls.AddRange(ctrls.ToArray());
}
```

I personally wouldn't recommend doing this, it's horrid, and I bet there will be a cleaner way to achieve what you want!

Comment: Works perfectly. I have onyl one problem now. The panel appears behind all the form1 controls. How can I bring that panel to the front? I tried to use c.BringToFront() inside foreach but it didn't work.

Comment: @user2858325...Um...to be honest...I have no idea apart from what you've tried. Like I said...it's a dirty hack, so you'll run into problems with it! Good Luck

Comment: The whole code will not copy or clone  but move the controls.